# #pragma deprecate a function based on signature?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, deprecated

in Visual Studio is it possible to #deprecated a function, based on the signature of the function and not simply the name?

In my case we're in C++ and don't want to deprecate all flavors of the function

```
int foo();        <-- we want to keep
int foo(int x);   <-- we want to deprecate
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do this:

```
__declspec(deprecated) void foo(int) {}
```

And if you want the compiler to generate a *specific* message when compiling a deprecated function, then do this:

```
__declspec(deprecated("foo(int) is a deprecated function.")) void foo(int) {}
```

Comment: Beat me by some 40 seconds. Damn you! +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

[deprecated may also be specified in a `__declspec()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx), (which is even better than the `#pragma` because it allows you to supply a reason if desired.